# Sharing Data between controllers : Service or Value?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

To share data between `controllers`, most of the Stack overflow Answers suggest to use `services`. Mostly when I share data between `controllers`, it is my application model(Data) and it changes in each `controller` as per application logic. So, should it not be an `angular value` instead of `angular service`?

For example, take the following `service`,

```
app.factory('Employee',function($http){
      function Employee(){
           this.data = {};
      }
      Employee.prototype.load = function(){
          //XHR call which invokes employee details and assigns it here
          $http.get(url).then(
                   function(response){
                         this.data = response.data;
                   }
          );
      }

      return new Employee();
});
```

With this service in hand, I would not be able to `inject` my `Employee` model during `ui-router`'s `resolve`(as `services` cannot be injected into `config` blocks). But if I create the same using `value`, I would be able to inject it during `stateRouting` itself. Could you please give me why `value` is not preferred to create models/share data between `controllers` over `service`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, values can't be injected into config blocks either. But that's irrelevant, since resolve functions are not called during the config phase, but at runtime, every time you navigate to the enclosing route.

Values can't be injected at all, so I don't really see how you would have access to $http when defining your value.

Finally, you *can* access your service in a resolve function, simply by injecting it into the function:

```
resolve: {
    employee: function(Employee) {
        return Employee.load();
    }
}
```

But that would not make much sense, since your load() method doesn't return anything. What it should do is **returning** a promise of employee:

```
Employee.prototype.load = function(){
    return $http.get(url).then(
        function(response) {
            return response.data;
        }
    );
};
```

But that has nothing to do with sharing data between controllers. What it allows doing is waiting for the employee data to be available and injecting it in the controller before switching to the employee view.

Comment: Thank you. It's my bad that with partial knowledge on angular services and incorrect demo's in my system I asked a question!